# Класс чтения XML файла с защитой от непредвиденных обстоятельств

Tags: xml, c++-cli

Мой вопрос скорее логический чем синтаксический.
Цель: получать и сохранять параметры из(в) xml

Написал такой класс:

.h

```
using namespace System::Xml::Linq;

/*
ЧТЕНИЕ ИЗ XML
*/
public ref class MBdat{
private:
    bool access = false;
    PathCombiner^ get;
    XElement^ options; 
public:
    bool access_MBdat();
    String^ load(String^ option);
    void save(String^ option, String^ value);
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "native.h"
#include "base.h"

bool MBdat::access_MBdat(){

try {
    options = XElement::Load(get->MBdat());
    access = true;
}
catch (Exception^ e) {
    access = false;
    MessageBox::Show(e->ToString());  
}
return access;
}

String^ MBdat::load(String^ option){
    String^ value = "";
    access_MBdat();
    if (access)
        value = options->Element(option)->Value;
    return value;
 }
 void MBdat::save(String^ option, String^ value){
     access_MBdat();
     if (access) {
         options->Element(option)->Value = value;
         options->Save(get->MBdat());
    }
    else
     {
         MessageBox::Show("Сохранение изменённых параметров не возможно, нет доступа к файлу настроек");
    }
}
```

При выполнении try в access_MBdat() программа уходит в catch
MessageBox выдает: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
Значит нужно объявить options правильно (gcnew XElement("контейнер"), но вот не задача, при таком построении вопроса options в классе должен быть глобальным, и поэтому я не могу объявить его сразу со ссылкой на файл, так как хочу обработать возможные ошибки (чертов уровень прав пользователей на доступ к файлам, особенно в Program Files).
Помогите идеями?

Comment: забыл указать, PathCombiner это мой класс, там я получаю абсолютный путь...

Comment: Хм, а напомните, что означает `get->MBdat()`?

Comment: Потому что валится, судя по всему, именно это выражение.

Comment: get->MBdat() = с:\document.xml

Comment: Окей, а какая именно строка валится? Если `get->MBdat()` не падает, и `XElement::Load` не падает (не должно ж), то откуда исключение?

Comment: вылктает строка 7:

Comment: options = XElement::Load(get->MBdat());

Comment: Ну, разбейте её на части, и проверьте, что именно вылетает: `get->MBdat()` или `XElement::Load`?

Comment: А вообще, чему равен `get`?

Comment: String^ PathCombiner::MODSdat() {
 String^ path = Path::Combine(GetExeDirectory(), "Mods.dat");
 return path;
}

Comment: Не-не, может быть `get == null` просто?

Comment: Вылетает get->MBdat(). Буду думать

Comment: Ну, а сам `get` не равен ли случайно `null`?

Comment: сам гет я проверял недавно, путь правильный
наверно класс объявил неверно
PathCombiner^ get;
надо так
PathCombiner^ get = gcnew PathCombiner();
Щас студия отпустит exe проекта, проверю. Кстати не знаешь чё она после компиляции по 5 минут не даёт доступа к exe проекта? Уж что не пробовал.. антивирус, брендмаувер, всё крутил.

Comment: да, ошибка была в объявлении класа. Так глупо)

Comment: Ну вот и хорошо, одной проблемой меньше :)